# Non-hosted version?

Tags: support, hosting

Stack Overflow could be very useful for my company, e.g. for new employees looking for answers on how company processes work. Is there a way to buy Stack Overflow as a product and to deploy it internally?

For obvious confidentiality reasons, there is no way we would accept a (private) hosted version.